# Variables Overview with xtable in R

Tags: r, statistics, xtable

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a `xtable` from the command `str(x)` to get an overview from the variables you use. This would be a nice feature to introduce someone to the dataset, but it's annoying to create it by yourself. So whta I tried is to make a `xtable` like this:

```
str(cars)
require(xtable)
xtable(str(cars))
```

the cars dataset is given from R. Unfortunately `xtable` doesn't give a Latexcode for `str()`. Is it possible outsmart R here? Here are the main commands that `xtable` will understand:

```
methods(xtable)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `xtable(summary(cars))`?

Comment: The problem with    str is that it doesn't give an output. Maybe `xtable(cars[1:10,])´

Comment: Hey Manoel! Thanks for your ideas, but i want to have a spezification of the variables. Something like car: integer ,Brand: factor (BMW,VW,Benz).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `xtable` provides best result when used with `data.frames` and `matrix` objects, I'd recommend something like this:

```
library(xtable)
library(plyr)
dtf <- sapply(mtcars, each(min, max, mean, sd, var, median, IQR))
xtable(dtf)
% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package                                                                  
% Thu May  5 19:40:08 2011                                                                                                   
\begin{table}[ht]                                                                                                            
\begin{center}                                                                                                               
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}                                                                                                
  \hline                                                                                                                     
 & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt & qsec & vs & am & gear & carb \\                                                       
  \hline                                                                                                                     
min & 10.40 & 4.00 & 71.10 & 52.00 & 2.76 & 1.51 & 14.50 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 3.00 & 1.00 \\                                      
  max & 33.90 & 8.00 & 472.00 & 335.00 & 4.93 & 5.42 & 22.90 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 5.00 & 8.00 \\                                  
  mean & 20.09 & 6.19 & 230.72 & 146.69 & 3.60 & 3.22 & 17.85 & 0.44 & 0.41 & 3.69 & 2.81 \\                                 
  sd & 6.03 & 1.79 & 123.94 & 68.56 & 0.53 & 0.98 & 1.79 & 0.50 & 0.50 & 0.74 & 1.62 \\                                      
  var & 36.32 & 3.19 & 15360.80 & 4700.87 & 0.29 & 0.96 & 3.19 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.54 & 2.61 \\                                
  median & 19.20 & 6.00 & 196.30 & 123.00 & 3.70 & 3.33 & 17.71 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 4.00 & 2.00 \\                               
  IQR & 7.38 & 4.00 & 205.18 & 83.50 & 0.84 & 1.03 & 2.01 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 2.00 \\                                     
   \hline                                                                                                                    
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                
\end{center}                                                                                                                 
\end{table}
```

Sorry for lengthy output. You can grab PDF [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8566396/each_xtable.pdf). `each` is a very versatile function, since you can define custom summary quite easy. Besides, `str` returns output to stdout, so you can't retrieve summary for specific variables. In this case, `sapply` will simplify the result, yielding `matrix` instead `data.frame`. But that's not so problematic, right?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! This is really helpful to me structuring xtable commands in the future! But I just need The Variables in a column and the levels, as it shown in the figure above! No need for any descriptive statistics :)

Comment: Well... that's something completely different. You should've said so. Could you rephrase your question, so we could tackle it in a different manner? Be sure to provide some dummy data.

Comment: <hello al3xa please hold on until tomorrow, when I'll give you some more information (it's close to midnight in Europe right now) of what I need, although it's is pretty close to what table 2 (above) provides! Just an overview over the data, the scales and if required levels for factors (for categorical data).

Answer (score 17):

Another package to look at is `reporttools`. Here is an short piece of code to illustrate its usage on the `tips` dataset from `reshape` package. Both the summary statements produce latex code which can be copy pasted into a document, or used for weaving.

```
library(reporttools)
data(tips, package = 'reshape')

# summarize numeric variables
tableContinuous(tips[,sapply(tips, is.numeric)])

# summarize non-numeric variables
tableNominal(tips[,!sapply(tips, is.numeric)])
```

EDIT. If you really MUST use `str`, then here is one way to go about it

```
str_cars = capture.output(str(cars))
xtable(data.frame(str_cars))
```

OUTPUT FROM REPORTTOOLS:[image][image]

Comment: Hello Ramnath! This is pretty close to what I need. Thanks so far! What I realy would like to have, is to merge the table for continous values and the categorical values! But what I don't need is the descriptive statistics... What I need is close to the str() command in basic R, but in a good looking way for Latex. Maybe this is not possible and I've to create a manuel table... I wonder why there is no simple command, because it's often neccessary to introduce variables, to make the reader familiar with what you're dealing with :)

Answer (score 14):

If you're willing to spend some time investigating how the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package works, you will soon discover that there are many utilities that facilitate such tasks. In particular, the `contents()` method facilitates the description of data.frame by reporting

> names, labels (if any), units (if
>   any), number of factor levels (if
>   any), factor levels, class, storage
>   mode, and number of NAs

Labels and units can be binded (internally, as `attributes`) to each variable.
There are associated `print`, `html` and `latex` methods for viewing and exporting.

Another nice functionality is the `describe()` function, as seen below:

```
> describe(cars)
cars 

 2  Variables      50  Observations
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
speed 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
     50       0      19    15.4     7.0     8.9    12.0    15.0    19.0    23.1 
    .95 
   24.0 

          4 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 23 24 25
Frequency 2 2 1 1  3  2  4  4  4  3  2  3  4  3  5  1  1  4  1
%         4 4 2 2  6  4  8  8  8  6  4  6  8  6 10  2  2  8  2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dist 
      n missing  unique    Mean     .05     .10     .25     .50     .75     .90 
     50       0      35   42.98   10.00   15.80   26.00   36.00   56.00   80.40 
    .95 
  88.85 

lowest :   2   4  10  14  16, highest:  84  85  92  93 120 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hey chl!
Very interesting Package. I tried the commands you presented and it seems to be worthy to spend some time learning to applicate! Just real quick: I tried to use the 'Latex(str(x))' command (I know this was just a noobish attempt) but it seems to be a different way to compute the Latex code (compared to the xtable command). I just need a short overview for variables as it is provided with str(). contents() and describe() are much better than str() to get some information about the data, but what I need to have is a short summarize!

Answer (score 0):

You may give a look also,

```
library(magrittr)
    library(qwraps2)

    mtcars2 <-
      dplyr::mutate(mtcars,
                    cyl_factor = factor(cyl,
                                        levels = c(6, 4, 8),
                                        labels = paste(c(6, 4, 8), "cylinders")),
                    cyl_character = paste(cyl, "cylinders"))

    our_summary1 <-
      list("Miles Per Gallon" =
             list("min" = ~ min(.data$mpg),
                  "max" = ~ max(.data$mpg),
                  "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$mpg)),
           "Displacement" =
             list("min" = ~ min(.data$disp),
                  "median" = ~ median(.data$disp),
                  "max" = ~ max(.data$disp),
                  "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$disp)),
           "Weight (1000 lbs)" =
             list("min" = ~ min(.data$wt),
                  "max" = ~ max(.data$wt),
                  "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(.data$wt)),
           "Forward Gears" =
             list("Three" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 3),
                  "Four"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 4),
                  "Five"  = ~ qwraps2::n_perc0(.data$gear == 5))
      )

    by_cyl <- summary_table(dplyr::group_by(mtcars2, cyl_factor), our_summary1)
    xtable(by_cyl)
```