# R describe and R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I'd like to `describe` my data table in a R Markdown file using

```
xtable(data, type='html')
```

But none of the packages I looked so far seem to be compatible with `xtable` in `html` setting, f.i. `Hmisc::describe`,`reporttools::tableNominal`.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Example:
Something like
[Variables Overview with xtable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900178/variables-overview-with-xtable-in-r/5901981#590198)
but working in Markdown/html.

Comment: Have you tried `R2HTML`?

Comment: @Thomas it would be easier for me to keep everything within one Rmd script

Comment: Of course, you don't want to use it's full output functionality. But you can do something like `R2HTML::HTML(data, file=stdout())` and keep everything self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found one option that does work well with R markdown and that is using the `psych::describe` command. This has the advantage that the final table is a `data.frame` object that can then be further manipulated.

with `xtable`

```
library(psych)
library(xtable)
table.desc <- describe(mytable)
print(xtable(table.desc), type="html")
```

or using `Gmisc`

```
library(psych)
table.desc <- describe(mytable)
table.prep <- as.matrix(table.desc)
library(Gmisc)
htmlTable(table.prep)
```

Please note that in this example you do want to include the rownames, as they are part of the `describe` output. Also `Gmisc` inherits the `Hmisc::describe` command and has thus to be loaded **AFTER** creating the stats table.

Comment: The `htmlTable` has moved to a separate package and no longer inherits Hmisc

Answer (score 4):

try pander package. specifically pandoc.table function from that package

```
> pandoc.table(head(mtcars), split.tables=Inf, style='rmarkdown')


|         &nbsp;          |  mpg  |  cyl  |  disp  |  hp  |  drat  |  wt   |  qsec  |  vs  |  am  |  gear  |  carb  |
|:-----------------------:|:-----:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|:------:|:-----:|:------:|:----:|:----:|:------:|:------:|
|      **Mazda RX4**      |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   | 2.62  | 16.46  |  0   |  1   |   4    |   4    |
|    **Mazda RX4 Wag**    |  21   |   6   |  160   | 110  |  3.9   | 2.875 | 17.02  |  0   |  1   |   4    |   4    |
|     **Datsun 710**      | 22.8  |   4   |  108   |  93  |  3.85  | 2.32  | 18.61  |  1   |  1   |   4    |   1    |
|   **Hornet 4 Drive**    | 21.4  |   6   |  258   | 110  |  3.08  | 3.215 | 19.44  |  1   |  0   |   3    |   1    |
|  **Hornet Sportabout**  | 18.7  |   8   |  360   | 175  |  3.15  | 3.44  | 17.02  |  0   |  0   |   3    |   2    |
|       **Valiant**       | 18.1  |   6   |  225   | 105  |  2.76  | 3.46  | 20.22  |  1   |  0   |   3    |   1    |
```

That markdown table should render as follows

[image]

Comment: Thanks @geektrader, I will try it out. I assumed that I needed to export it using `pandoc`, that's why I hadn't tried it yet.

Comment: @geektrader - Thanks for promoting `pander` :) Just a small addition that could improve the usability of the package: one can set the `style` of all tables and if splitting of tables is required or not with [`panderOptions`](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#pander-options) and then simply call `pander` on any R object.

Comment: Darn, I'm working within a secure environment, which is too old to support the `pander` package [Revolution R Community, R 2.14.2]

Comment: Of course this still assumes that the table you want to plot is in some sort of table format, which is NOT true for `describe` output